# How to create new personality in the IDE using open tools API?

Tags: delphi

How to create new personality in the IDE using open tools API (OTA)? I couldn't find any documentation or any demo covers this section in OTA.

Thanks.

Comment: A new personality? What exactly do you mean? In RAD studio, they use the term *personality* to indicate which is your main language, Delphi, C++ etc. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Exactly, new personality to create different kind of projects (different language maybe) and also to configure the MSBulid to use different compiler.

Comment: @Iassam What makes you think this is even possible?

Comment: @David there are methods in the Personality service (in the OTA) like (AddPersonality, RemovePersonality, AddPersonalityTrait…) which means that it is possible. At least that what the methods say ;-)

Comment: @Issam I doubt you'd get very far with this. Even if it's possible to do all that you want, and I doubt that, I can't find any documentation. I think if you want an IDE that is extensible enough to host new languages then I'd look at Eclipse or Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks David, I know it’s a difficult mission, but, Let us wait to see if someone else can give us any hint, someone from "inside" maybe ;-)

Comment: Good luck with this. I'm guessing it's possible but almost certainly completely undocumented. From what I've heard though that's the same situation that RemObjects faced when they developed Prism (then Chrome) for Visual Studio.

Comment: UI Designer support would be pretty difficult I imagine unless you were able to support the VCL from your language. That doesn't mean you can't have a personality without UI designer support though. I think it was RAD Studio 2007 in which the C# personality was limited so that you could only edit and compile code, no UI designer support was available for it.

Comment: @LachlanG Thanks a lot for your comments, in my case I don’t want to implement a new designer I just need to edit and compile code. So, it would help and save a lot of time if anybody can give us the general steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the answer to your question "How" --

To add a language personality to the IDE, you must contact the RAD Studio R&D team and get special permission from the company to have access to non-public packages, interfaces, and APIs.

As shipped, there is no way to add a language personality to RAD Studio.

Now, having said that, as of Delphi XE it is /much/ easier to add a module into the Code Editor and Project Manager.  There was a lot of work done by the IDE team to make adding items into the Code Editor, and that is available in XE.

Comment: Has anyone ever given this a go Nick?

Comment: The AQTime people are the only one's I know that have gone beyond -- and I'm not sure if their integration is considered a personality or not.

Comment: Thanks Nick, as usual the one who care about community ... Appreciate your answer and it is very much accepted :)

Comment: You are welcome -- I even got to earn the "Revival badge"  :-)